# Can this be done with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Here is what I would like to do.

Say I have Class Widget.

I then create Button from Widget.

I then create ModifiedWidget which re-implements certain functions of Widget.

I then want Button to use ModifiedWidget rather than plain Widget. Is this possible to do some how?

Thanks

```
class Button : public Widget;

class SuperButton : public Button, public ModifiedWidget;
```

I'm just not sure if that would do what I want it to though.

Comment: Not very well formed question. As it is written, it sounds as if you just change which parent button derives from.

Comment: Please clarify.  Isn't this just a case of `class Widget {...}; class ModifiedWidget : public Widget {...}; class Button : public ModifiedWidget {...};`?

Comment: It's still not clear what your question is!  It now sounds like this is a fairly standard multiple-inheritance relationship (albeit a *diamond* relationship).

Comment: @Milo
Then what are you asking. Just change Button to derive from ModifiedWidget. There is no multiple inheritance.

Comment: Why do that much. Now even if that worked, you asking the compiler to expect two different implementations of Widget's methods.

I could understand a diamond being a problem, but you're making a triangle.

Comment: You're breaking the foundation of OO. Polymorphism would make no sense in this case.

If you really need two implementations of Widget's methods.... why not write new methods in modified widget (instead of overriding base methods) and just derive from only Modified widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use encapsulation, not inheritance.

```
class Button
{
    Button(Widget * w) { mywidget = w; }
    Widget * mywidget;
};
```

Another way is to let Button be a template class.

```
template<class Parent>
class Button : Parent
{
};

Button<Widget> mybutton1;
Button<ModifiedWidget> mybutton2;
```

Comment: encapsulation doesn't reflex Liskov principle well: Button **is** a Widget, and Button users would like to use it as Widget. templated version resolves this problem using Widget as a mixin

Comment: @Andy T, I've found that the is-a relationship is too easy to assume, and often it can be changed without too much trouble. Not sure about this case, which is why I gave the two-for-one answer.

Comment: Button and SuperButton may have different implementation. So he may need to extend Button<ModifiedWidget>, but then what have we gain? Template approach is more complicated than multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, this is typical [Dreaded Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)

With some care, it is possible, although I suggest reconsidering your design, because multiple inheritance can be often avoided (which brings simpler and cleaner design).

Also [Read C++ Faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8) on Dreaded Diamond

In reply to your example, you will have to use virtual inheritance for Button and ModifiedWidget classes.

```
class Button : public virtual Widget;

class ModifiedWidget : public virtual Widget;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep them separate:

```
class Widget {
    ...
    virtual void some_function();
};

class ModifiedWidget : public Widget {
    ...
    // override the base version of this method
    virtual void some_function();
};

class Button {
    Button(Widget* w) : widge(w) { }
    Widget* widge;
};

class SuperButton : public virtual Button {
    SuperButton(Widget* w) : Button(w) { }
};
```

Now your `Widget`s have a hierarchy, and your `Button`s have their own hierarchy.  And it probably makes more sense to say that your Button *contains* a Widget, than to say that your Button *is* a Widget.  Thus, we go with encapsulation instead of inheritance for the Button-Widget relationship, but still have inheritance for the Buttons and Widgets separately.